# Can I remove my vent covers without disconnecting the duct?

Tags: hvac

I have an old house with flexible duct work in the ceiling. There is mold in at least one. Can I remove the vent covers to clean or will that disconnect the duct work in the attic from the vent cover/diffuser?

[image]

Comment: A photo of the vent covers might be useful, since there are many available and we don't know what type you have.

Comment: Picture added now

Comment: I don't really get how you could clean all of the ductwork of mold? Your arms are only so long...

Comment: If that is an exhaust fan from a bathroom, it will always have moist air in the ducts.  Some mold might grow there, but the air will be exhausting outside, not into the house.  How much mold did you see?

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of duct work.  Install new duct work or at the very least clean the crap out of old duct work with mold products and bleach (but then again do you want the chemicals pushing through your house).

I would install rigid duct if possible.  If your flex got mold and you didn't "fix" the issue of why it got mold then your new flex will probably get mold too.  I would then wrap your rigid duct in plastic then insulation.

And just to your answer.  Yes unscrew your vent cover, it won't hurt anything.

Comment: I just moved in Feb. I would like to do as you advise but I have to wait until I can afford it. As far as the source of the mold I am still trying to figure that out. In the mean time I have to live here. Can I remove the duct covers/diffusers on the ceiling without affecting the attic duct work?

Comment: Rigid duct is like $10 per 4 feet and really all you need are some snippers and a screwdriver to install.  Why do you want to remove the duct covers?

Comment: To clean inside with a mold removal product

Comment: How long is this duct work?  For the price of the mold product and bleach you could probably replace it.  You do clean it and put it back up please wash it with soap and water a day later and then let it sit outside another day.  Don't put it right back up after spraying mold removal products which are probably much worse for you than mold.